# why is it ecmascript instead of javascript and why do ecma websites look like they are circa 1999?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, ecmascript-5

Since JavaScript is becoming more and more popular I'm wondering who are the people who get to decide what the language looks like, and why do we have ECMAScript instead of JavaScript? The ECMA sites look very outdated...are these the people in charge of the future of the web that drives all the groovy stuff like V8, and NodeJs?

I love JavaScript and I love NodeJs...but there seems to be some controversy on what's going into the newest script languages. I guess that can't be avoided. I'm just excited about the future of JavaScript and hope we are in good hands.

http://www.ecma-international.org/default.htm

http://www.ecmascript.org/

Comment: You could watch the first episodes of [Douglas Crockfords talk about JS](http://javascript.crockford.com/#video). He talks quite a bit about the history of it.

Answer (score 5):

[JavaScript is a trademark owned by Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Trademark). The language is standardized by the [ecma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecma_International), (previously the European Computer Manufacturers Association).

[Netscape submitted the language to them in 1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#History), to promote a single standardized client-side language (at the time, MS had a similar language called JScript), and the goal was to avoid browser specific implementations (like we have with CSS now). The ecma simply maintains the default sets of [expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript), not any individual implementations.

No individual is responsible for all the development in ECMAscript. V8, Node, jQuery, WebRTC, etc. are all incredibly valuable projects supported or maintained by disparate (sometimes collaborating) groups.

Additionally, each browser implements ECMAscript differently, so "what goes into the new language" is not under any one individual or organization's control.

Just because there's a standard, doesn't mean everyone, or anyone will follow it. Trust me, you should see my code. :)